# How can I block my website in other countries?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, web-development, canonical-url, ecommerce

Lets assume my website is mywebsite.com. I need to block the website for all the countries except India. But we need to handle the block gracefully, i.e. showing a page that right now the site is not providing services in their country.

Page on my website visible in India: 
mywebsite.com/category.php

When someone outside India opens the website they should see the following URLs:
mywebsite.com/world/category.php

Kindly note that Google Search should always show the URLs without "world" in there.

Following are the solutions I have on mind:

**Scenario:** Someone tries to open mywebsite.com/category.php from US. 
The code will check for the IP location and the user would be redirected to mywebsite.com/world/category.php

**Solution1:** Add no follow and no index tags on mywebsite.com/world/category.php so that Google does not index this page and use a 302 redirection. This page will be served to everyone from outside India.

**Solution2:** Add a 302 redirect from mywebsite.com/category.php to mywebsite.com/world/category.php 
and also add canonical on mywebsite.com/world/category.php as website.com/category.php

Problem in this approach is loop for Google bot, first we are doing a redirect and then we are putting a canonical to the one which as redirected. Sounds wrong to me but I am not sure.

**Note:** This question is related SEO strategy. I want your suggestions on my SEO strategy. I do not want any technical solution for redirection from .htaccess or IP blocking outside India traffic .

Answer (score 2):

Filter visitors by .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^IN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://Mywebsite/Indiapage.php [L]
```

And for the rest you redirect to world/worldpage

Comment: That looks like it requires something else to make it work.  Maybe the IP2Location Apache module?  https://www.ip2location.com/developers/apache

Comment: That is correct it's enabled by default on my servers so I tend to forget that not everyone has it. Well the idea stays the same he should allow IPs from India and redirect anything else to /world

Comment: Thank you for reply, I do not want any technical answer for .htaccess redirection or IP blocking. I want to know whether my strategy is correct or not from SEO point of view..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ip range for India
http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/in.html

use above address and codes below (you need to enter ip ranges by yourself)

```
<?php
$deny = array("1.6.0", "1.22.0", "223.224.0");
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
header("location: http://mywebsite.com/world/category.php");
exit();
} ?>
```

or this

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "14.102") === 0))
{
die();
}
```

you need to do some work but this is the way that I can think of. You can try use wildcard for php (*) for the similar ip ranges

Comment: Please don't do this with php. If you're going for this method, use htaccess with a redirect. Much MUCH faster end resource friendly.

Comment: That PHP code won't work, either, as it is technically incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I do not want any technical answer for .htaccess redirection or IP blocking. I want to know whether my strategy is correct or not from SEO point of view.. I have updated my question kindly review.